# How to scroll a list of items in ListView if an Dialog is opened in android?

Tags: android, dialog

I have an Activity containing a list of products using ListView. If I click on any product A than a dialog is opened and this product A is added into the dialog. To to add another Product B I want to scroll list of product while dialog is opened.
But I am not able to scroll list.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a dialog, the view/activity in the back is uncontrollable. What you can do is add a View on top of the ListView and play with the setVisibility(View.***) method, which will display the contents of the dialog you wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but is it not possible scroll listView or click on item of listview while dialog is opened?

Comment: No. You've to use fragments or SurfaceView

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to open the default android dailog LIstView with scroll .Here is some code sample which is working correctly.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        DialogActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");

builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
        "cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

builderSingle.setAdapter(
        arrayAdapter,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DialogActivity.this);
                builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                builderInner.setPositiveButton(
                        "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
builderSingle.show();
```

Comment: I don't want to add list of item in a alert dialog. I just want to scroll or click the item of a listView of an Activity while a dialog is opened.

Comment: okay...for that you have to design your custom dialog and bind it with the Adapter.but if you are looking to open list view you can use above code and make your adapter just bind it in dialog box